# Wagtail: How to hide field B option if field A has been filled in the editors interface?

Tags: interface, customization, wagtail

I'm new to Wagtail. The problem I meet right now is this:

I create a block called article box, which contains an image field with an intro field or an external link field. Intro and external link should not exist at the same time. In the editor's interface, I want the external link field to disappear if the intro field has been filled or vice verse. Is this possible in Wagtail? If yes, how? And any useful information I can get from the Wagtail official tutorial?

Answer (score 2):

I'd love to see something like this added as a configurable option they provide in Wagtail core, but they have added a [hook](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.6.3/reference/hooks.html#insert-editor-js) that you can use to define your own Javascript functions to handle these things.